# Wowza Rest API equivalent to Java SDK createInstance()

Tags: wowza

I am working on converting an old app that uses the Wowza Java SDK into one that uses the Wowza Rest API. This is for a hosted Wowza Streaming Engine.

I can't figure out the equivalent of this SDK call:

```
Stream.createInstance​(IApplicationInstance appInstance, String sName)
```

The SDK says this is used to create a named Stream on an application instance, and returns a com.wowza.wms.stream.publish.Stream.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The REST API and Java SDKs do not completely overlap in functionality.

The REST API was designed to power the Wowza UI, so can be limited in its functionality. I do not believe you can go deeper than configuring the server, managing applications, etc.  The same things you can do in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

You can start a new app instance by the following REST API call (PUT request):

```
/v2/servers/{serverName}/vhosts/{vhostName}/applications/{appName}/instances/{instanceName}/actions/start
```